# How to multiple URLs on same router link

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm working on a little test project in angular and I want to include a side navigation using angular router outlet. I want there to be two links:

```
<a class="nav-link text-white" [routerLink]='["/link/to/one"]' routerLinkActive="aLink" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">Component 1</a>
<a class="nav-link text-white" [routerLink]='["/another/link/to/component"]' routerLinkActive="aLink" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">Component 2</a>
```

There are a few sub pages that can be navigated to from one of the components. But they don't need to show up as a router link.

So the structure of my site can be for example:

```
|-Comopnent 1
|
|-Component 2
   |- Component 3 
   |- Component 4
```

So I want the user to be able to navigate to Component2 via the router links. From this component the user can be redirected via code to component 3 and 4. But I dont want them to have extra router links, I want that there is still component2 highlighted in the navigation menu.

In my app.module.ts I declared the routes pretty basically:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: '/link/to/one', component: Component1 },
  { path: '/another/link/to/component', component: Component2 },
])
```

How can I call Component3 & 4 from Component2, and let the router highlight Component2 in the navigation bar?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by simply setting `Component3` and `Component4` to show on Child Routes.

So your Router Config will be something like:

```
[
  { path: 'one', component: OneComponent },
  { path: 'two', component: TwoComponent, children: [
      { path: 'three', component: ThreeComponent },
      { path: 'four', component: FourComponent },
    ] 
  },
]
```

And then the `routerLinkActive` will take care of the rest.

In the `active` CSS Class, I've set the `color` to `red`. So whichever link is active, it will get the red color.

You can also test it out by manually typing `/two/three` or `/two/four` in the address bar.

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/router-link-active-on-parent-links-only) for your ref.

Answer (score 2):

### TL; DR

Configure your `Component 3` and `Component 4` route as children of `Component2`, and then remove your `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"` from your `routerlink` linked to `Component2`.

### Description

I think you already know the answer, the key is `routerLinkActiveOptions`.

First, configure your route like this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: '/link/to/one', component: Component1 },
  { path: '/another/link/to/component', component: Component2, children: [
      { path: '/component3', component: Component3 },
      { path: '/component4', component: Component4 },
    ],
  },
])
```

Then, change your `routerLinkActiveOptions`

Before:

```
<a class="nav-link text-white" [routerLink]='["/another/link/to/component"]' routerLinkActive="aLink" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">Component 2</a
```

After:

```
<a class="nav-link text-white" [routerLink]='["/another/link/to/component"]' routerLinkActive="aLink" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: false }">Component 2</a
```

The difference is `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: false }"`.

However, the default value of `routerLinkActiveOptions.exact` is `false`, so it is same with just removing the `routerLinkActiveOptions`.

```
<a class="nav-link text-white" [routerLink]='["/another/link/to/component"]' routerLinkActive="aLink">Component 2</a
```